# Laravel Blade how to fetch parent relation data

Tags: one-to-many, laravel-blade, laravel-5.5

I have two models connected according to below relationship. A *Customer* can have many projects whereas a *Project* can only have one *Customer*. Suppose my below models implements above described relationship.

**Field definitions**

*Project*

`id`, `description`, `customer` (<= `customer` is the foreign key which refers `Project.id`)

*Customer*

`id`, `description`

---

**Project model:**

```
public function customer()
{
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customer', 'customer', 'id');
}
```

**Customer model:**

```
public function projects()
{
  return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Project');
}
```

---

**ProjectController:**

```
public function index()
{
  return view('project.index', ['projects' => Project::with('customer')->paginate(10)]);
}
```

---

**Blade view:**

```
@foreach ($projects as $project)
<tr>
  <td><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/edit">{{$project->id}}</a></td>
  <td>{{$project->description}}</td>
  <td>{{$project}}</td>
  <td>{{$project->customer->id}}</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

---

But `$project->customer->id` gives `Trying to get property of non-object...` error.

If I print one of the Projects inside foreach loop, I get below dataset.

```
{
  "id":1,
  "description":"te",
  "state":"Preliminary",
  "customer":{"id":1,"description":"Test Customer","created_at":"2017-10-19 23:29:27","updated_at":"2017-10-19 23:29:27"},
  "created_at":"2017-10-25 19:06:50",
  "updated_at":"2017-10-25 19:06:50"
}
```

Can someone help me figure out the reason why I cannot refer *Customer.id* as `$project->customer->id`?

Comment: can you please show me your `dd($projects)` response?

Comment: Try $project->customer()->id.

Comment: @Mr.Pyramid Thank you for your hint. I just got a dd response and I figured it out that I should use `$project->Customer->id`. I had used `customer` instead of `Customer`. (Y)

Comment: pleasure happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should use `$project->Customer->id`. Note that it should be ***C***ustomer instead of *customer*.